# autosuggest with 40million values

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have an DB with 40 million values and I am using autosuggest with jquery and the suggestion is getting very slow. I need know two things: how can I speedup with this data (using mysql db with php) and will java with any other db improve the speed?

Comment: Do you load on demand or all at once?

Comment: limit your autosuggest to the first 10 or so values that match

Comment: You're kidding me about that last sentence, right?

Comment: And/or are you using a database search or a xml file search? or some other data set?

Comment: @David Mårtensson i just load just 10 values per suffix match

Comment: Please provide your PHP code/database query; and details of the db table (including indexes)

Comment: Please post your DB schema, as well as the method used to return data to the autosuggest, are you doing LIKE searches? etc.. fulltext? etc... details

Comment: Could you please post the query you are using for autosuggest now?

Comment: The JQuery autocomplete control gives you MANY options about when to load data.  You could increase the wait time between when the user stops typing and you do your lookups (so you will often have more characters to do a lookup with).  Is the slowness happening in the Javascript, or the query?

Comment: As an alternative, if you will, you could use Solr which performs way better on this task than using MySQL http://www.mattweber.org/2009/05/02/solr-autosuggest-with-termscomponent-and-jquery/

Comment: It is far more likely that using a different approach will improve speed more than changing languages.  You could consider caching the auto suggestions, say the last 1,000 or 10,000 queries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- be sure to have an index on the matching field. either an exclusive index or the first segment of the index.
- be sure to use `LIKE 'xxx%'` (where xxx is the input so far); **never** `LIKE '%xxx%'`
- be sure to limit the results with `LIMIT 10` on the database, **never** on the app.

**edit**: borrowing from [bpeterson76's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807424/autosuggest-with-40million-values/4807667#4807667):

- don't do `SELECT *`, get only the fields you need.
- don't search single-character, wait until you have at least 3 or so
- don't search too quickly, wait at least 100msec between queries.

Answer (score 3):

I have one going in PHP/MySQL with about 2 million records, here's what's worked for me:

1. I use `REGEXP` rather than `like`, and it's working fine.
2. Limit the query to return only the values you need (name, etc)  This sounds obvious to most quality developers, but I've seen `select *` done for things like this in the past.
3. Index, Index, Index.  This made the single most difference that I've found so far.
4. Limit autosuggest to start on character 3 (for example) instead of character 1.
5. Add in a delay to the autocomplete.  If someone is typing away to refine the list, there's no reason to fire until they've stopped (or slowed down) for a reasonable period.  This can save quite a few hits to the db.

I use both the newer Jquery UI autocomplete and its predecessor from Jorn over at [bassistance.com](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) that includes additional features including caching that didn't make the official UI release.  You might give that version a try to see if it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Assert you have proper index, as noted above.

Additionally, don't kill your database with too much queries. The database is easilier killed by 100 queries taking 10 rows each than 10 queries taking 10 rows each.

So, after user typed, say, 3 letters, ask for a bit more data than you display.
Say, you display 10 rows, take 100.

When user types another letter, it's high propable that 10 next values will be among this 100. So you will be sending less queries to database.

In most optimistic case the value the user search for will be fetched in 1 or 2 queries.

Additionally, remember the buffer so you wan't be forced to send query again when user deletes last character.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few more suggestions...

- Use `SQL_CALC_ROWS` in the `SELECT` and a subsequent `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` if you need to find out the total  number of items when you're using a `LIMIT` in the same query
- Try and see if you can use [Fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) search (MySql has pretty good support for that), which is significantly faster than using expressions like `LIKE '%xxx%'`
- Use EXPLAIN command to find out where the bottlenecks in your query are, and to be sure that indices are used
- Make sure that the query is the problem, and not PHP or something else (do this by benchmarking only the queries where you get bad results)

Answer (score 0):

> 40 million values

I really can't believe you have so much data AND you want to use autocomplete for it.

> I am using autosuggest with jquery and
>   the suggestion is getting very slow.

The data returned should be in MEMORY because that's a lot faster than memory. You should use [Redis](http://redis.io) because it is l[ightning fast in MEMORY database](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks). The author has even written a blog post how to write [an Auto Complete with Redis](http://antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html).

> and will java with any other db
>   improve the speed?

I would use [node.js](http://nodejs.org) because it is extremely fast(But is not necessary redis and Java/PHP will also work) and easy to use.

- Use one of these techniques to install node.js + npm => https://gist.github.com/579814. I really enjoy npm. Especially if I compared(personal) too Maven.
- `npm install express hiredis redis`